# Material-ui v.1 - MenuItem passing outer index onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In my component I have a `Table` with generated rows from some custom array of objects. In the last `TableCell` I want to have a icon button that on click opens `Menu` with some `MenuItem` actions (edit and delete). This is my code:

```
{folders.map(folder => {
return (
    <TableRow key={folder.id} >
        <TableCell>{folder.name}</TableCell>
        <TableCell>
            <IconButton
                onClick={this.handleFolderActionClick}>
                <MoreHoriz />
            </IconButton>
            <Menu onClose={this.handleFolderActionClose} >
                <MenuItem onClick={event => {onEditFolder(event, folder)}}>
                    <ListItemIcon>
                        <Edit />
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText inset primary="Edit" />
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={{event => onDeleteFolder(event, folder)}}>
                    <ListItemIcon>
                        <Delete />
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText inset primary="Delete" />
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
);
})}
```

The `onClick` event is always passing the last folder element in the array and not the one mapped to that particular `TableRow`.
I've read that `MenuItem` `onClick` event should not be used in this manner but I don't have any other idea how to solve my specific problem. I'm opened for any suggestions. How to pass object from the outer map function to `onClick` event of `ManuItem`?

Edit:
[Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/0x8lnylqj0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using *currying* to avoid inlining your menu item handlers and make them more readable (and avoid possible syntax-related bugs, which I believe you have). You would define the handlers like this:

```
onEditFolder = folder => event => {
  // edit click handler
}
onDeleteFolder = folder => event => {
  // delete click handler
}
```

And then use them in your render (inside your `folders.map` loop) like this:

```
<Menu onClose={this.handleFolderActionClose}>
  <MenuItem onClick={this.onEditFolder(folder)}>
    <ListItemIcon>
      <Edit />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText inset primary="Edit" />
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem onClick={this.onDeleteFolder(folder)}>
    <ListItemIcon>
      <Delete />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText inset primary="Delete" />
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

You can do this because `onEditFolder(folder)` returns a function that expects an event, as per its definition. Same for `onDeleteFolder(folder)`.

Note: I added the `this` keyword as a prefix for both functions, that would be assuming they're defined inside the same component where they are used. If you pass them as props, modify accordingly.

**FOLLOW-UP**:
The error had nothing to do with the mapping, but was caused by both menus relying on the same boolean value to toggle open or close, causing the last menu to display regardless of which item was clicked.

I corrected this by creating a `menus` array in state, with length set to that of the size of the list and all values initialized to `false` (this is done in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method). Menu open & close and close handlers were updated to pass the index of the list item, and updating the value in the `menus` array to `true` or `false`, accordingly. The `open` attribute of each `Menu` component was set to the corresponding entry in the `menus` array, in order to show/hide the menu based on the corresponding value.

Finally, both `Menu` components had the same `id`, I corrected that as well.

[See working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pvwljkp7q).

Comment: Unfortunately the folder param in `onEditFolder` function is undefined when I try using currying. Any idea why?

Comment: If it's undefined in the function, then it's undefined when you pass it as an argument to that function in the map loop. Have you tried logging the value of `folder` at the beginning of each map iteration (before the return statement)?

Comment: It seams that there is a problem on my side so I've created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0x8lnylqj0). As you can see array item is passed to the function but it's always the last one in the array.

Comment: The error was not related to the mapping, but caused by your using the same boolean to set the `open` attribute of your menus. See updated answer (including modified sandbox) for details.